# How to base64 encode apache header?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-headers, base64

I'm using apache as a frontend http proxy. I need to send a header with a value from a specific environment variable to all proxied request. Like this:

```
RequestHeader set myheader %{FOO}e
```

The issue is that the value from the env variable `FOO` must be base64 encoded. Is it possible to b64-encode that header value on the fly?

mod_rewrite? subrequest? a custom module? ...

Btw, the env variable is created by another apache module, which I cannot fix unfortunately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. Using mod_rewrite to read/write stdin/stdout from an external program like this:

```
ProxyRequests on
RewriteEngine on

# 1 
RewriteMap base64map "prg:/bin/b64e" 

# 2
RewriteRule .* - [E=WIC:${base64map:%{QUERY_STRING}},NE]  

# 3
RequestHeader set x-b64encoded "%{ENV:WIC}e" 

# 4
RewriteRule ^proxy/.*$ http://localhost:9999 [P]
```

1. Create a rewrite-map named `base64map` which runs the executable (`/bin/b64e`) which reads stdin and encodes on stdout.
   The executable is loaded when apache starts and you have to make a loop reading from the stdin and passing it through the / bin / base64 for it to work well
2. The rewrite rule passes the query string (or whatever you want) to the mapping named `base64map`. The output is used to set the apache variable `WIC` to the encoded value.
3. The request header `x-b64encoded` is created from the value in `WIC`
   To correctly read the WIC variable we had to change the syntax to ENV: WIC
4. Finally, the request is proxied to the destination and the header is automatically included with the request.

Answer (score 5):

Using an [expression](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html) with the `base64` [function](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html#functions) should also work:

```
RequestHeader set myheader "expr=%{base64:%{FOO}e}"
```

Used it successfully to perform an additional base64-encoding pass on a client certificate as follows:

```
RequestHeader set X-ENV-SSL_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE "expr=%{base64:%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s}"
```

Comment: Would rather be:
`RequestHeader set myheader "expr=%{base64:env:FOO}"`
But this does not work.